# Email application giving error "No applications can perform this action"

Tags: android, email

I am trying a simple email application.I referred this link
http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-email-in-android/

But i am getting an error "No applications can perform this action" on emulator as well as on real device.How to overcome this error.Also as mentioned in the above link on send button,Choose an email client option appears.How to obtain this?Can someone guide me plz.
Thanx in advance.
My code is:

```
package com.example.androidsample4;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MakeComment extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.comment);
        TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView tv4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        TextView tv5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        final EditText ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final EditText ed3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        final EditText ed4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        ed3.setKeyListener(null);
        Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  //String to = ed3.getText().toString();
                  String name = ed1.getText().toString();
                  String message = ed4.getText().toString();

                  Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                 // email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ to});
                  //email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{ to});
                  //email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{to});
                  email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, name);
                  email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

                  //need this to prompts email client only
                  email.setType("message/rfc822");

                  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: You should gmail installed in your device or eumalator

Answer (score 1):

It won't work on the emulator unless you install an application that can handle email. By default no such app is installed. Try to install an email client on your real device and re-test this.

Comment: Ok i will try this and let u know

Answer (score 1):

This will display only email apps in your chooser:

```
     private void sendMail() {
        String recipientList = "recipient@gmail.com,recipient2@gmail.com";
        String[] recipients = recipientList.split(",");

        String subject = "App Subject - Help me";

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                "mailto","emailaddress@gmail.com", null));
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an Email Client"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
            "mailto","abc@gmail.com", null));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "EXTRA_SUBJECT");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

We can't tell you where you are wrong as you have not posted your code. Try the below code(works both on device and emulator), if it works then there something wrong on your part and if doesn't try installing another e-mail client.

```
TextView email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
email.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"mailto:youremail@gmail.com\">E-mail</a>"));
email.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

"Choose an email client option" - That window is automatically populated by Android.

Comment: Change Intent.ACTION_SENDTO to `Intent.ACTION_SEND`